# Como alterar a cor do navbar ios

Tags: ios, swift, nav-bar, uinavigationcontroller

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação, gostaria que a barra de navegação tivesse a mesma cor do corpo do projeto, estou tentando com o seguinte código

```
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Esse código funciona, altera para cor vermelha, porém eu queria de uma outra cor e tentei o seguinte código

```
navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 23, green: 27, blue: 113, alpha: 1)
```

e também tentei esse outro

```
let corBarra = UIColor(red: 24, green: 27, blue: 113, alpha: 1)
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = corBarra
```

Alguém tem ideia de como fazer para alterar para uma cor que já nao seja pré definido?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que voce tem que passar um valor entre 0.0 e 1.0. Se voce passar qualquer valor acima disso ele interpreta como 1.

```
let corBarra = UIColor(red: 24/255, green: 27/255, blue: 113/255, alpha: 1)
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = corBarra
```

Se voce quiser voce tambem pode criar o seu próprio initializer:

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(r: Int, g: Int , b: Int , alpha: CGFloat) {
        self.init(red: CGFloat(r)/255, green: CGFloat(g)/255, blue: CGFloat(b)/255, alpha: alpha)
    }
}
let corBarra = UIColor(r: 24 , g: 27, b: 113, alpha: 1)   // r 0.094 g 0.106 b 0.443 a 1.0
```

Comment: Obrigado Leo, resolveu meu problema. Grato

Comment: De nada Kleiton. Se precisar de ajuda com a data no formato iso8601 me avisa. Abs

Comment: Leo, mais uma dúvida cara
Voce sabe me dizer como que posso trocar o texto do botão "back" do navbar, o default aparece "<back" queria colocar pra "<voltar" ou uma imagem que se tornem mais intuitivo

Comment: Assim de cabeça eu não lembro mas acho que o certo é sempre usar localized string. eu vou procurar alguma referencia e te falo. Abre outra pergunta.

Comment: Ok Leo, obrigado pela disposição, vou criar uma pergunta